# I need to rewrite Java "for" to "while" and "do"

Tags: java

i made a "for" a while a back ago now i need to change it to a "While" and change that to a "do", any help would be appriciated

```
for(int i = 3; i <= 10; i++) {
  System.out.print(" " + i);
  if(i % 10 == 0)
    System.out.print("\n");
}
System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem with your approch?

Comment: I hope you're not trying to let stackoverflow do your homeworks ... ;)

Comment: do my homework... never thats blashmaphy :D @fievel

Answer (score 3):

A [for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

```
for (ForInit; Expression; ForUpdate) Statement
```

is equivalent to the [while statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12):

```
{
  ForInit;
  while (Expression) {
    Statement;
    ForUpdate;
  }
}
```

Converting a `for` to a `while` is simply a matter of cutting+pasting into this template.

`for` loops don't map onto to a `do/while` cleanly, because the `Expression` needs to be evaluated before `Statement`. You *could* do this:

```
{
  ForInit;
  do {
    if (!Condition) break;

    Statement;
    ForUpdate;
  } while (true);
}
```

but that's just horrible; you should be using a `while` statement instead.

Comment: alright i understand the principle ill read into what you just explained :)